# What are the files can be deleted in a windows server?

Tags: windows

What are the files which can be deleted in a windows server running IIS where the drives are getting filled up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove redundant user profiles, clear out %TEMP% and IIS logs.  Empty the recycle bin (you never know what's hanging around in there!).

Answer (score 3):

You can delete all the subdirectories in "C:\WINDOWS\" whose names begin with "$NtUninstall*", provided you don't want to uninstall any of the patches to the operating system.

Those subdirectories are hidden, so make the adjustments necessary to Explorer.exe to be able to see them.

Answer (score 1):

How about the IIS log files?

Comment: The log files are already batched to rar itself for 'n' days in the machine. Is there a way to delete identify all the temp directories in a windows machine which will speedup the process

Answer (score 1):

The only files that should be filling up the disk are the IIS log files, the system log files and the files used for the web site(s).  The system log files might be setup to autoarchive especially in a DoD system.  Check %system%\System32\Config to see if you have a bunch of event logs.

Your other options are to expand the partition or get larger drives.